# Get daylight savings time (DST) for year

Tags: php, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm working with an API that requires DST details for the year that first interval in a time series data falls on.

For example, for an account located in `America/Chicago` I need to know:

```
# If data starts in 2014
DST Start: 2014-03-09 02:00:00
DST Stop:  2014-11-02 02:00:00

# If data starts in 2009
DST Start: 2009-03-08 02:00:00
DST Stop:  2009-11-01 02:00:00
```

PHP has good DataTime functions but how can I find DST details for specific year? I don't want to resort to adding/subtracting arbitrary interval and checking whether or not the date is in daylight savings time `$dt->format('I')`.

I know PHP uses `tzdata` internally which has all those details but are they exposed? Is there any way to get that data natively in PHP? If not, is there linux utility that I could `exec()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [DateTimeZone class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) has a method called [getTransitions()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) that returns this information